# calculate dimension of a module as a vector space

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $F$ be a field, $ f\in F[x] $ an irreducible polynomial and $n$ a positive integer.

Show that the $F$-vector space $F[x]/f^nF[x]$ has dimension $n\deg(f)$.

I thought of using the chinese remainder theorem, but since $f$ is not prime with itself, I can't.
Then I tried to write the explicit basis : $\{1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^{n\text{.deg($f$)-1}} \}$, but I have trouble proving this intuition

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

- For any polynomial $g\ne 0$, $\;\dim_F F[x]/gF[x]=\deg g$. To prove it use *Euclidean division* by $g$ in $F[x]$.
- $\deg f^n=n\deg f$.